# Matched pairs design: individual confidence intervals for pre and post

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, paired-data, contingency-tables

I have a matched pairs design. I have a 2x2 table showing success/failure in pre and post:

|  | Post (yes) | Post (no) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pre (yes) | 0 | 10 |
| Pre (no) | 20 | 30 |

My colleague would like a confidence interval on the proportion of post (yes). How can I obtain one?

My start: The observations are conditionally independent given the "pre" status, right?

So can I just use the standard Wald-type CI: $\hat{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}$, where $\hat{p} = (0+20)/(0+10+20+30)$, $z_{\alpha/2}=1.96$ for a 95% confidence interval and $n=0+10+20+30 = 60$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, yes you can.  You could consider incorporating a log or logit link function, i.e.

$$\text{exp}\Big( \text{log}\{\hat{p}\}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\Big[\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}\Big]/\hat{p}\Big)$$

$$\text{or}$$

$$\text{logit}^{-1}\Big( \text{log}\Big\{\frac{\hat{p}}{1-\hat{p}}\Big\}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\Big[\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}\Big]/[\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})]\Big).$$

The log link function is useful if your estimates are near 0 and your sample size is small.  The logit link function is useful if your estimates are near 0 or near 1 and your sample size is small.  Your estimate of $20/60=0.33$ is not close to zero by most standards, but the link functions may still help to improve the coverage of the confidence interval.  For your estimate of $0.33$ they will shorten the lower confidence limit and lengthen the upper limit relative to a Wald interval using an identity link.  Here log refers to the natural log with base $e$.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Wald with identity link | (0.21, 0.45) |
| Wald with log link | (0.23, 0.48) |
| Wald with logit link | (0.23, 0.46) |

With your sample size all of the intervals look similar.

If, for example, you had witnessed 3 events in a sample of size 30 then the confidence limits would be

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Wald with identity link | (-0.01, 0.21) |
| Wald with log link | (0.03, 0.29) |
| Wald with logit link | (0.03, 0.27) |

Of course we would never report a negative proportion so the lower limit using the identity link would be truncated to 0 (not inclusive).

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, thanks for your thoughts. Do you have any references to support the idea regarding the coverage? I'm just wondering if there's a compelling argument for using this method with the log-link function instead of the standard method.

Comment: Any text book on generalized linear models would cover it.  I like the books by Agresti.  The idea is we are approximating the binomial sampling distribution with a normal distribution.  When the true $p$ is near 0 and the sample size is small the binomial sampling distribution is better approximated by a log-normal.  If you run a regression in Proc Genmod with dist=bin and link=log your exponentiated coefficients are risk ratios.

Comment: Is there a method that would guarantee the bounds would be within the interval [0,1]? Because I know Wald intervals can result in bounds outside that interval, which doesn't really make sense for a CI on a proportion....

Comment: The logit transformation provides this guarantee so long as your point estimate is not exactly 0 nor exactly 1.  In that case I would invert the CDF of a binomial distribution to obtain a one-sided confidence bound.  Inverting a binomial CDF works in any situation, but is not easily written in a closed form.

Comment: The log link guarantees the lower limit will not go below 0.  This is useful if you are estimating small proportions.